# How to use Java as Orbeon Form's back end logic and the where the generated xhtml source code stored at?

Tags: xml, xhtml, orbeon, xforms, exist-db

As mentioned in the title above, i really cannot find relevant tutorial or information in the web. Really hope that you guys can provide me some tutorial link or video so that i can learn about it.

The location of generated xhtml is actually talking about this scenario. I deploy the CE version of Orbeon Form using Tomcat, then run it in localhost:8080/orbeon. I tried to create a form at there, but after i save and publish the form, i cant search where is the generated file located. i wish to access the generated code, where can i find the code?

after reading the answer provided by inanda, i having another new doubt that, is there a version actually created a form and it is save in file system?

Really wish that i can get some direction or idea how to do it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form is not saved in file system, it saves the form in database. For your case, it's saved in eXist db, which is a XML database bundled with Orbeon.

Look how to view the code: [How to view the source of an Orbeon form saved in eXist-db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387090/how-to-view-the-source-of-an-orbeon-form-saved-in-exist-db)

If you want to use another database to save your forms instead of Exist, take a look at: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers

You can use java code by adding a jar file which has your classes to lib folder inside Orbeon.
Then you can edit source manually and add a namespace to xhtml:html tag, like:
xmlns:yourNameSpace="java:com.yourJavaClassName"

After it, you should be able to call the methods from your class in XPath expressions, for example for constraint validations: yourNameSpace:yourMethodName(parameters) .

It's also possible to make Rest calls or call a WebService by using the XForms submissions.
Take a look at: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/fb-fr/call-service

Comment: thank you for the reply.
is that possible that i use a java code to control the action perform in the form? if yes, how can i do it?

Comment: i having another new doubt that, is there a version actually created a form and it is save in file system?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any version/configuration which saves it in file system. I've edit my answer to show a possibility to use your java code.

Comment: @InandaMenezes is correct, you cannot save the form to the filesystem automatically. You *could* manually extract the generated form definition from the database, save it to the filesystem, and configure an Orbeon resource manager to load the form definition from there. Or save it to a special location in the WAR file. But that is a lot of trouble to go through if you don't have a really good reason for doing it.

Comment: @ebruchez we have written our own persistence api to store the form definitions as text files as we save and publish the form inside formbuilder.  This is so we can then store the xform code in a Git repo.  I'm wondering whether it may be quicker if we went back to using the existdb and extracting the code directly.

Comment: @jtb I don't have a definite opinion on this. Clearly maintaining a persistence layer is some work. If you use eXist or a relational database, you can use the REST API to retrieve form definitions and data, but that probably means you need to poll the database at regular intervals unless you can put a trigger in place.